# Set column header's style in vaadin's table

Tags: styles, vaadin

Is it possible to set unique style to each column header in vaadin's table?
There's method setCellStyleGenerator which works only for the contents - not for the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; as far as I am aware, this is not currently possible.
Do feel free to submit a Feature Request : https://vaadin.com/bug